# Best way to design Data WareHouse DWH

Tags: database, oracle11g

I have question about creating Data warehouse.
We have system that generate more than 50 million records per day, I do some pre-process in these records then load them to table in data base.

Now you should see the problem which is: the size of single table and the how you can manage it (after about ~15 days of load ~50M record/day) and I need to keep records from 60-days old.

Now my question is: the best way to design my data warehouse is:

- to use different table for every day or for every let say week.
- OR use single table with many partitions.
- OR some other Approach that you find is better for my case?

I need Headline to start my designing for DWH. I'm using Oracle 11g as my database.

Comment: Use google and search for: Oracle Data Warehousing guide, fact table, star/snowflake schema.

Comment: The issue is not with to many tables but with one large table the we can not normalize it to be in star/sonwflake schema. But thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use partitioning if it's available.

Partitioning gets you the best of both worlds.  You can access all your data at once, in one simple table.  If the query predicates or partition name syntax is used correctly the table will act like it's magically much smaller than it really is.  And you can manage the data by day - bulk operations like loading and dropping data can be done in a way that only affects a single day's worth of data.

Interval partitioning makes things even easier.  You don't even have to specify the partitions.  Just tell Oracle, "make each day a new partition".  There are a few new things to learn.  But it's a small price to pay for a significant boost in performance and manageability.

If you're using Enterprise Edition and have already licensed the partitioning option then there's no reason not to use it.